# How to compute the average vector of a set of vectors in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a RDD of the form

```
(3,CompactBuffer((-0.063763,0.060122,0.250393), (0.006971,-0.096478,0.123718), (-0.198281,-0.079444,-0.015460)))
```

I need to calculate the average of the vectors in the compactBuffer

```
val averagevector = filteredvectors.reduce((a,b) => sum(b)/b.size)
```

By doing a reduce Action something like the one shown above.

My `averagevector` should be something like `(3, (avg(1), avg(2), avg(3)))` where `avg(1)` is the average of all the first elements in the `CompactBuffer` shown above.

Comment: Are the inner tuples always of length 3? or the tuples in a buffer of same length?

Comment: Inner tuples are not necessarily of length 3. But it os given that they are of same length.